# Replace a paragraph with a city name from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

While building a weather app I faced a problem. It has to automatically detect where we based and provide with appropriate temperature and location e.g city name. I'm trying to replace p with a data from JSON. In particular I'm trying to replace paragraph with a city name. For some reason it doesn't work.

http://codepen.io/ekilja01/full/KaMXjp/

Here is my **HTML**:

```
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <i class="fa fa-thermometer-empty fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <br><br><br>
            <form>
                <input type="radio" name="celsiusOrFahrenheit"    value="fahrenheit"> Fahrenheit &deg;F;<br>
            <input type="radio" name="celsiusOrFahrenheit" value="celsius" checked> Celsius &deg;C<br>
           </form>
  <div class="yourlocation">
    <h1>Your location is: </h1>
     <p class="yourLocationGoesHere">
     </p>
 </div>

 <h1>Your current weather is: </h1>

     <div class="showTemperature">
       <p class="showDegree">32</p>
      </div>

      </div>
</body>
```

Here is my **jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather? q=London,uk&appid=7f5806c8f3fd28b03e2d6580a50732d6", function (data){

   var len = data.length;
   var html = "";

   html += "<p>'" + len.name + "'</p>";
   $(".yourLocationGoesHere").html(html);
  });
});
```

Here is my **JSON**:

```
{"coord":
{"lon":145.77,"lat":-16.92},
"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken             clouds","icon":"04n"}],
"base":"cmc stations",
"main":{"temp":293.25,"pressure":1019,"humidity":83,"temp_min":289.82,"temp_max":295.37},
"wind":{"speed":5.1,"deg":150},
"clouds":{"all":75},
"rain":{"3h":3},
"dt":1435658272,
"sys":{"type":1,"id":8166,"message":0.0166,"country":"AU","sunrise":1435610796,"sunset":1435650870},
"id":2172797,
"name":"Cairns",
"cod":200}
```

Please help.

Comment: You have a bug here: `html += "<p>'" + len.name + "'</p>";` it should be `html += "<p>'" + data.name + "'</p>";`

Comment: Beware though, that apart from an obvious data error, your code generates a faulty, invalid html, where a `<p>` element contains another `<p>` element. Instead of the two lines dealing with `.html` you should be using `$('.yourLocationGoesHere').text(data.name)` alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` is refering to your json document, so it should be:

```
html += "<p>'" + data.name + "'</p>";
```

The `len` variable just holds the length ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Much appreciated.

Comment: I think they are there for style reasons

Answer (score 1):

You were trying to get the city name of the length of the JSON **which is wrong**. Simply do :

> data.name

Here's working solution. Hope it helps!

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather? q=London,uk&appid=7f5806c8f3fd28b03e2d6580a50732d6", function (data){

        var len = data.length;
        var html = "";

        html += "<p>'" + data.name + "'</p>";
        $(".yourLocationGoesHere").html(html);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you Henry but Fabian provide an answer earlier. Much appreciated anyway!